# Google Chrome doesn't use my installed Gtk theme, but other apps do

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and then I installed gtk-master dark theme (dracula dark theme) for applications and gnome shell.

Now when I open Google Chrome, it still uses the old theme and not the Gtk theme. I have checked it is 64-bit rather than 32-bit. It works fine in firefox.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you have set Chrome to use the GTK+ theme and not the Classic one by following these steps:

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click the icon with the three vertical ellipses (<kbd>⋮</kbd>) on the top right of the browser and select *Settings*.
3. Inside *Settings* select *Appearance* on the sidebar on the left.
4. In the *Theme* section click <kbd>Use GTK+</kbd>.

   [image: Google Chrome Appearance settings]

Comment: yeah thank you it works

Answer (score 1):

5. In the url enter `chrome://flags`

search for Preferred Ozone and select your backend ex: `Wayland`

[image: screenshot]